# Uploading to Google Drive using meteor meteor-slingshot

Tags: google-drive-api, meteor-slingshot

Trying to implement Slingshot for Google Drive.

(Using a service account for storing application specific files).

In this scenario, there is no way to know the download url until the upload is complete. It is a difficulty while implementing the upload function. (If I do as two separate uploads, one for meta data( separate post outside of Slingshot transfer method), I could get the download url and pass the id in the return parameters, however, that's inefficient. Ideally, need a way to get the download url from the xhr response. Plus, need a way to send the file meta data and the file as multi-part.

Anyone?

Comment: What authentication method are you using for google drive? Can you provide a link to the docs?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Server-to-server OAuth 2.0 flow by using Google APIs nodejs client library.Two-legged OAuth or 2LO 
 * Application uses a service account to use Google Drive API to upload a Word Document and convert to HTML. 
 * To support server-to-server interactions, first create a service account for the project in the Developers Console.

 * You need the service account email address and the p12 key file.